# Block internet on 1 network adapter while using 2nd network adapter for everything else

Tags: windows, networking, internet

My PC has 2 network adapters.

#1 is used for work connection through hardware VPN box

#2 is in my local network.

I use #2 through my local network to RDP (remote desktop) to the device. The issue is that I want to have network adapter #2 accessible on my local network so that I can RDP to it from any local device, but not have any internet access at all so the PC will not try to use it for outgoing connections. Currently, I block all incoming and outgoing traffic to network adapter #2 it through my router, but I wanted to be more specific and do it on the PC itself and cut down on network traffic so there was 0% chance it would try to use it for anything rather than just deny it on my router with the chance of the PC attempting to retry over and over. Is there a way to do this from within windows 10?

Comment: Could you add a bit more context to this? (1) You mention “the device” without introducing or describing it. Briefly, what is it? (2) You say that you use adapter #1 “for work”. You don’t need to give any details, but what does this mean? *Are you **at home** or **at work** (or somewhere else)?* Are you working from home? Do you have a home business? (When you say that you are using “your PC” for work, but you don’t want the PC to have Internet access, it raises these questions.) … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Why do you think that this will cut down on network traffic?

Comment: Hello @Scott and @ harrymc. I updated my post. I am at home with a device I use through work that has 2 network adapters.

Comment: @harrymc: I’m still not 100% clear, but it looks like Aaron wants to (1) prevent software on the PC from “phoning home” to get updates and do malicious things like exfiltrate data, and (2) avoid creating a route between the Internet and the employer’s internal network. If so, this may be a duplicate; it sounds like something that has been asked before. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … P.S. If you block Windows Update from working, Bill Gates will come to your house and ask for an explanation.    :-)    ⁠

Comment: If the poster wants to block apps from phoning home, this is a job for the firewall.